# What does a box with a plus inside signify?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a paper I recently came across a simple mathematical symbol I've never seen before. It's a square with a cross inside and looks like this: [Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/975bL.png)

The question asks which of the following options would hold true with respect to this equation: [Three Possible Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zNjG.png)

I would appreciate it if someone knew the name of this symbol and what it's characteristics are.

Comment: It means $a\ln b-b\ln a$.

Comment: Looks like a generic symbol for a binary operation. It signifies whatever you say it signifies.

Comment: it is the symbol for the operqation defined on the RHS, that is to say that like in 'normal' mulitplication $a \times b= ab$. This symbol is defined as $a \ln b - b \ln a$. The 'possible answer' are there for you to prove I think, show that given the definition above, those relations hold.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which paper?

Comment: I got the answer (a) which is correct. @Qmechanic I am doing a past paper from a Swedish entry exam (Q6): https://bit.ly/2KhCACA

Comment: What does part (d) mean on that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) holds true, just compare both sides by writing $$a\ln(b)-b\ln(a)$$ and $$-(b\ln(a)-a\ln(b)$$The result is clearly the same.

With the other two, unless I'm missing something, are false.

$$1\ln(b)-b\ln(1)=\ln(b)-0=\ln(b)\not=b$$
and
$$a\ln(b^2)-b^2\ln(a^2)=2a\ln(b)-b^2\ln(a)$$
$$2[a\ln(b)-b\ln(a)]=2a\ln(b)-2b\ln(a)$$